# I am making a PHP quiz app. How do I make sure the questions are asked only once?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session

I have an array of ten questions and answers. I used `arry_rand` and `shuffle` to randomize questions and shuffle the answers.

How do I make sure that the questions are asked only one time? After I loop through all ten questions I want the game to be over. Thank you for the help!:)

Here is what I have so far.

```php
include ("inc/questions.php");
session_start();

$pageTitle = "Math Quiz: Addition";

$_SESSION["score"]= 0;
if ((isset($_SESSION["score"]) && $choices[0]["correctAnswer"])){
    $_SESSION["score"] += 1;
}
echo $_SESSION["score"];

$rand = array_rand($questions,1);
shuffle($questions);

$choices = [
    $questions[0]["correctAnswer"],
    $questions[0]["firstIncorrectAnswer"],
    $questions[0]["secondIncorrectAnswer"],
];
shuffle($choices);

if ((!isset($_SESSION["counter"]) || $_SESSION["counter"] >9)) {
    $_SESSION["counter"] = 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION["counter"] += 1;
}
?>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo "$pageTitle";?> </title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="quiz-box">

                <p class="breadcrumbs"> <?php echo "Question Number "  . $_SESSION["counter"] . " of " . "10"; ?>
                <p class="quiz"><?php echo "What is " . $questions[0]["leftAdder"] . " + " . $questions[0]["rightAdder"];?></p>
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer1" value="<?php echo $choices[0];?>" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer2" value="<?php echo $choices[1];?>" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer3" value="<?php echo $choices[2];?>" />
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the array of questions and answers:

```php
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 3,
    "rightAdder" => 4,
    "correctAnswer" => 7,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 8,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 10,
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 16,
    "rightAdder" => 32,
    "correctAnswer" => 48,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 52,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 61,
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 45,
    "rightAdder" => 12,
    "correctAnswer" => 57,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 63,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 55,
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 42,
    "rightAdder" => 18,
    "correctAnswer" => 60,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 69,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 57
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 96,
    "rightAdder" => 20,
    "correctAnswer" => 116,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 120,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 110
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 44,
    "rightAdder" => 85,
    "correctAnswer" => 129,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 132,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 126
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 51,
    "rightAdder" => 35,
    "correctAnswer" => 86,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 96,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 82
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 5,
    "rightAdder" => 61,
    "correctAnswer" => 66,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 65,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 74
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 26,
    "rightAdder" => 19,
    "correctAnswer" => 45,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 40,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 39
];
$questions[] =
[
    "leftAdder" => 26,
    "rightAdder" => 35,
    "correctAnswer" => 61,
    "firstIncorrectAnswer" => 59,
    "secondIncorrectAnswer" => 51
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by shuffling the questions only once per session, and keeping that shuffled version in a session variable, each time popping off one question.

Some other issues:

- You reset the score *every* time to zero.
- To check that the user submitted the right answer, you need to look into the `$_POST[]` array

You could use this code:

```
// Check submitted answer is correct:
if (isset($_SESSION["correctAnswer"]) && isset($_POST[$_SESSION["correctAnswer"]])) {
    $_SESSION["score"] += 1;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION["score"]) {
    $_SESSION["score"] = 0;
    $_SESSION["counter"] = 0;
    shuffle($questions);
    $_SESSION["questions"] = $questions;
}

echo "score = " . $_SESSION["score"];

if (count($_SESSION["questions"]) == 0) {
    // Here you should navigate to a game-over page that 
    // displays the score and allows to start again (clearing the session).
    die ("No more questions");
}

// Get next question
$currQuestion = array_pop($_SESSION["questions"]);
$_SESSION["correctAnswer"] = $currQuestion["correctAnswer"];

$choices = [
    $currQuestion["correctAnswer"],
    $currQuestion["firstIncorrectAnswer"],
    $currQuestion["secondIncorrectAnswer"],
];
shuffle($choices);

$_SESSION["counter"] += 1;
```

In the rest of your code replace the occurrence of `$questions[0]` with `$currQuestion`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am at work now but will try it as soon as I get home!

Comment: I'll look more into the $_POST array while I am at work!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$rand = array_rand($questions,1);
shuffle($questions);
```

do

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="quiz-box">
<?php

    shuffle($questions); 
    for($i=0; $i<count($questions); $i++) {
?>
            <p class="breadcrumbs"> <?php echo "Question Number "  . $i . " of " . "10"; ?>
            <p class="quiz"><?php echo "What is " . $questions[$i]["leftAdder"] . " + " . $questions[$i]["rightAdder"];?></p>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0"/>
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer1" value="<?php echo $choices[$i][0];?>" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer2" value="<?php echo $choices[$i][1];?>" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="answer3" value="<?php echo $choices[$i][2];?>" />
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php

    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've been struggling for days. I'm at work now but will give it a try when I get home.